# How to pass VM NIC keys to Load Balancer module using output block in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules

I am trying to associate specific Virtual Machine NIC IPs to Load Balancer Backend pool using  `azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association` resource. Since I have specific requirement to map only specific VM NIC ips to backendpool pool. So, I have created a mapping in `vm_nic_to_lb_bpool_map`.

Below is my module folder structure

[image]

I am sharing complete code

**loadbalancer module**

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "lb" {
  for_each            = var.loadbalancers.tiers
  name                = each.value.lb_name
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = var.existing_resource_group
  sku                 = "Standard"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                          = "fip-${each.value.fip_name}"
    subnet_id                     = each.value.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = each.value.private_ip_type
  }

}

resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "probe" {

  depends_on = [azurerm_lb.lb]
  for_each = {
    for lb in flatten([
      for lb_name, lb in var.loadbalancers.tiers : [
        for probe_name, probe in lb.lb_probes : {
          lb_name_value  = lb.lb_name
          lb_name        = lb_name
          probe_name     = probe_name
          protocol_value = probe.protocol
          port_value     = probe.port

        }
      ]
      ]
    ) : "${lb.lb_name}-${lb.probe_name}" => lb
  }
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.lb[each.value.lb_name].id
  name            = each.value.probe_name
  protocol        = each.value.protocol_value
  port            = each.value.port_value

}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "bepool" {

  depends_on      = [azurerm_lb.lb]
  for_each        = var.loadbalancers.tiers
  name            = each.value.backend_address_pool_name
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.lb[each.key].id

}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "rule" {

  depends_on = [azurerm_lb.lb]
  for_each = {
    for lb in flatten([
      for lb_name, lb in var.loadbalancers.tiers : [
        for lb_rule, rule in lb.lb_rules : {
          lb_name                 = lb_name
          lb_rule                 = lb_rule
          frontend_port           = rule.frontend_port
          protocol                = rule.protocol
          backend_port            = rule.backend_port
          enable_floating_ip      = rule.enable_floating_ip
          frontend_ip_config_name = rule.frontend_ip_config_name
          probe_name              = rule.probe_name
        }
      ]
      ]
    ) : "${lb.lb_name}-${lb.lb_rule}" => lb
  }

  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.lb[each.value.lb_name].id
  name                           = each.value.lb_rule
  protocol                       = each.value.protocol
  frontend_port                  = each.value.frontend_port
  backend_port                   = each.value.backend_port
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = azurerm_lb.lb[each.value.lb_name].frontend_ip_configuration[0].name
  enable_floating_ip             = each.value.enable_floating_ip
  backend_address_pool_ids       = [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.bepool[each.value.lb_name].id]
  probe_id                       = azurerm_lb_probe.probe["${each.value.lb_name}-${each.value.probe_name}"].id

}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "nic_lb_association" {
  for_each = var.vm_nic_to_lb_bpool_map

  network_interface_id    = var.virtual_machine_nic_keys[each.key].id
  ip_configuration_name   = var.virtual_machine_nic_keys[each.key].ip_configuration[0].name
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.bepool[each.value].id
}
```

**loadbalancer variables**

```
variable "loadbalancers" {
}

variable "existing_resource_group" {
  type = string
}

variable "virtual_machine_nic_keys" {
}

variable "vm_nic_to_lb_bpool_map" {
}
```

**Virtual machine module**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = var.existing_resource_group
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {

  for_each = {
    for vm in flatten([
      for vm_name, vm in var.virtual_machines.nodes : [
        for nic_name, nic in vm.networks : {
          vm_number      = vm.vm_num,
          vm_name        = vm_name,
          nic_name       = nic_name,
          subnet_value   = nic.subnet
          nic_name_value = nic.nic_name

        }
      ]
      ]
    ) : "${vm.vm_name}-${vm.nic_name}" => vm
  }
  name                = "${var.vm_prefix}-${each.value.nic_name_value}-nic"
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = var.existing_resource_group

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.vm_prefix}-${each.value.nic_name_value}-ipconfig"
    subnet_id                     = each.value.subnet_value
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {

  depends_on                      = [azurerm_network_interface.nic]
  for_each                        = var.virtual_machines.nodes
  name                            = "${var.vm_prefix}-${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.vm_num}"
  admin_username                  = "plutoadmin"
  admin_password                  = "pluto@1234522"
  disable_password_authentication = false
  location                        = "eastus"
  resource_group_name             = var.existing_resource_group
  network_interface_ids           = [for nic_key, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic : nic.id if startswith(nic_key, "${each.key}-")]
  size                            = "Standard_B2ms"

  os_disk {
    name                 = "${var.vm_prefix}-${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.vm_num}-OSdisk"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "RedHat"
    offer     = "RHEL"
    sku       = "82gen2"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

**Virtual Machine output**

```
output "vm_nics_ids" {

  value = [for nic_key, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic : nic.id]
}

output "virtual_machine_nic_keys" {
  value = merge([
    for vm_name, vm in var.virtual_machines.nodes :
    {
      for nic_name, nic in vm.networks :
      "${vm_name}-${nic_name}" => azurerm_network_interface.nic["${vm_name}-${nic_name}-nic"].id
    }
  ]...)
}
```

**virtual machine variables**

```
variable "vm_prefix" {
  type    = string
  default = "pluto"
}

variable "virtual_machines" {
}

variable "existing_resource_group" {
  type = string
}
```

**main.tf**

```
module "virtualmachine" {
  source                  = "./virtualmachine"
  existing_resource_group = var.existing_resource_group
  virtual_machines        = var.virtual_machines
  vm_prefix               = var.vm_prefix
}

module "loadbalancer" {
  depends_on               = [module.virtualmachine]
  source                   = "./loadbalancer"
  existing_resource_group  = var.existing_resource_group
  loadbalancers            = var.loadbalancers
  vm_nic_to_lb_bpool_map   = var.vm_nic_to_lb_bpool_map
  virtual_machine_nic_keys = module.virtualmachine.virtual_machine_nic_keys

}
```

**tfvars**

```
    existing_resource_group = "pluto"
    existing_infra_rg       = "pluto-infra"
 
    virtual_machines = {
      nodes = {
        app1_node1 = {
          "vm_name" = "app"
          "vm_num"  = "1"
          networks = {
            nic1 = {
              "nic_name" = "app-1"
              "subnet"   = "/subscriptions/************/resourceGroups/pluto/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/pluto-infra/subnets/app-subnet"
            },
          }
        },
        service1_node1 = {
          "vm_name" = "service"
          "vm_num"  = "1"
          networks = {
            nic1 = {
              "nic_name" = "service-1"
              "subnet"   = "/subscriptions/************/resourceGroups/pluto/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/pluto-infra/subnets/app-subnet"
            },
          }
        },
        db1_node1 = {
          "vm_name" = "db"
          "vm_num"  = "1"
          networks = {
            nic1 = {
              "nic_name" = "db-1-1"
              "subnet"   = "/subscriptions/************/resourceGroups/pluto/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/pluto-infra/subnets/app-subnet"
            },
            nic2 = {
              "nic_name" = "db-1-2"
              "subnet"   = "/subscriptions/************/resourceGroups/pluto/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/pluto-infra/subnets/db-subnet"
            }
          }
        },
        db2_node2 = {
          "vm_name" = "db"
          "vm_num"  = "2"
          networks = {
            nic1 = {
              "nic_name" = "db-2-1"
              "subnet"   = "/subscriptions/************/resourceGroups/pluto/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/pluto-infra/subnets/app-subnet"
            },
            nic2 = {
              "nic_name" = "db-2-2"
              "subnet"   = "/subscriptions/************/resourceGroups/pluto/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/pluto-infra/subnets/db-subnet"
            },
          }
        },
      }   
    }
       
    loadbalancers = {
      tiers = {
        app-lb = {
          lb_name                   = "app-loadbalancer"
          fip_name                  = "app-fip"
          subnet_id                 = "/subscriptions/************/resourceGroups/pluto/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/pluto-infra/subnets/app-subnet"
          private_ip_type           = "Dynamic"
          backend_address_pool_name = "app-bpool"
    
          lb_probes = {
            tomcat-probe = {
              protocol = "Tcp"
              port     = "8080"
            }
          }
          lb_rules = {
            tomcat-rule = {
              frontend_port           = "7070"
              protocol                = "Tcp"
              backend_port            = "8080"
              enable_floating_ip      = true
              frontend_ip_config_name = "app-loadbalancer"
              probe_name              = "tomcat-probe"
            }
          }
        },
        db-lb = {
          lb_name                   = "db-loadbalancer"
          fip_name                  = "db-fip"
          subnet_id                 = "/subscriptions/************/resourceGroups/pluto/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/pluto-infra/subnets/app-subnet"
          private_ip_type           = "Dynamic"
          backend_address_pool_name = "db-bpool"
    
          lb_probes = {
            db-probe = {
              protocol = "Tcp"
              port     = "8080"
            }
          }
          lb_rules = {
            db-rule = {
              frontend_port           = "7070"
              protocol                = "Tcp"
              backend_port            = "8080"
              enable_floating_ip      = true
              frontend_ip_config_name = "db-loadbalancer"
              probe_name              = "db-probe"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    vm_nic_to_lb_bpool_map = {
      "app1_node1-nic1" = "app_lb"
      "db1_node1-nic1"  = "db_lb"
      "db2_node2-nic2"  = "db_lb"
    }


**variables**

variable "resource_group_location" {
  type    = string
  default = "eastus"
}

variable "vm_prefix" {
  type    = string
  default = "pluto"
}

variable "virtual_machines" {
}

variable "existing_resource_group" {
  type = string
}

variable "loadbalancers" {
}

variable "vm_nic_to_lb_bpool_map" {
}
```

**ERROR :**

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on virtualmachine\output.tf line 11, in output "virtual_machine_nic_keys":
│   11:       "${vm_name}-${nic_name}" => azurerm_network_interface.nic["${vm_name}-${nic_name}-nic"].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_network_interface.nic is object with 6 attributes
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

could someone help to find the error root cause or how to write output variable in virtual machine to output the virtual machine nic keys that matches the vm_nic_to_lb_bpool_map ?

Expecting the below association
`"app1_node1-nic1" = "app_lb" "db1_node1-nic1"  = "db_lb" "db2_node2-nic2"  = "db_lb"`

**non-module code working as expected with below code**

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "nic_lb_association" {
  for_each = local.vm_to_lb_map

  network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc[each.key].id
  ip_configuration_name   = azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc[each.key].ip_configuration[0].name
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.bepool[each.value].id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to pass VM NIC keys to Load Balancer module using output block using terraform and I was able to provision the requirment successfully.

You are getting this error because of how you defined the output variable `virtual_machine_nic_keys` in your `virtualmachine` module. The error means that the collection `azurerm_network_interface.nic` does not have the key you are using to access it. Therefore, the keys you are using and the keys in the `azurerm_network_interface.nic` map do not match.

To resolve this issue, let's focus on the relevant portion of your Terraform configuration:

```
`output "virtual_machine_nic_keys" {
  value = merge([
    for vm_name, vm in var.virtual_machines.nodes :
    {
      for nic_name, nic in vm.networks :
      "${vm_name}-${nic_name}" => azurerm_network_interface.nic["${vm_name}-${nic_name}-nic"].id
    }
  ]...)
}`
```

To overcome the issue double-check that the NIC names you're constructing keys with (`"${vm_name}-${nic_name}-nic"`) match exactly how they are named when creating `azurerm_network_interface.nic` resources. The error suggests there's at least one key that doesn't match.

**My terraform configuration:**

**main.tf:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "examplevk-rg"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "testvk-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "testvk-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "lb_pip" {
  name                = "testvk-public-ip"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

module "vm" {
  source              = "./modules/vm"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  vm_prefix           = "vktdestvm"
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  virtual_network_id  = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
   vm_configurations   = {
    vm1 = {
      size           = "Standard_B2s",
      admin_username = "adminuser",
      admin_password = "SecurePassword123!",
      subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    }
  }
}

module "loadbalancer" {
  source              = "./modules/loadbalancer"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  public_ip_id        = azurerm_public_ip.lb_pip.id
    vm_nic_ids          = {
    "vm1" = {
      ip_address         = "10.0.0.4" // Example IP, replace with actual dynamic reference
      virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
    }
    // Add more VMs as needed
  }
  lb_config = {
    name = "myLoadBalancer"
    sku  = "Standard"
    frontend_ip_configs = [
      {
        name         = "myFrontendIPConfig"
        public_ip_id = azurerm_public_ip.lb_pip.id
      }
    ]
    backend_pools = [
      {
        name = "myBackendPool"
      }
    ]
    health_probes = [
      {
        name         = "myHealthProbe"
        protocol     = "Http"
        port         = 80
        request_path = "/"
      }
    ]
    lb_rules = [
      {
        name                       = "myLoadBalancingRule"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        frontend_port              = 80
        backend_port               = 80
        frontend_ip_config_name    = "myFrontendIPConfig"
        backend_address_pool_name  = "myBackendPool"
        probe_name                 = "myHealthProbe"
        enable_floating_ip         = false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### `modules/vm/main.tf`:

```
variable "resource_group_name" { type = string }
variable "location" { type = string }
variable "subnet_id" { type = string }
variable "vm_prefix" { type = string }

variable "virtual_network_id" {
  description = "The ID of the virtual network where the VMs are connected."
  type        = string
}

variable "vm_configurations" {
  description = "Configurations for VMs."
  type = map(object({
    size           = string
    admin_username = string
    admin_password = string
    subnet_id      = string
  }))
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  for_each           = var.vm_configurations
  name               = "${var.vm_prefix}-${each.key}-nic"
  location           = var.location
  resource_group_name= var.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "main" {
  for_each            = var.vm_configurations

  name                          = "${var.vm_prefix}-${each.key}"
  resource_group_name           = var.resource_group_name
  location                      = var.location
  size                          = each.value.size
  admin_username                = each.value.admin_username
  admin_password                = each.value.admin_password
  network_interface_ids         = [azurerm_network_interface.main[each.key].id]
  disable_password_authentication = false

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

output "vm_nic_details" {
  value = {for k, v in azurerm_network_interface.main : k => {
      ip_address = v.ip_configuration[0].private_ip_address
      virtual_network_id = var.virtual_network_id # Assuming you have this variable declared and passed correctly
  }}
}
```

#### `modules/loadbalancer/main.tf`:

```
variable "resource_group_name" { type = string }
variable "location" { type = string }
variable "public_ip_id" { type = string }
variable "vm_nic_ids" {
  description = "A map of VM NIC IDs to their properties."
  type = map(object({
    ip_address         = string
    virtual_network_id = string
  }))
}


variable "lb_config" {
  description = "Load balancer configuration."
  type = object({
    name                = string
    sku                 = string
    frontend_ip_configs = list(object({
      name           = string
      public_ip_id   = string
    }))
    backend_pools = list(object({
      name = string
    }))
    health_probes = list(object({
      name         = string
      protocol     = string
      port         = number
      request_path = string
    }))
    lb_rules = list(object({
      name                       = string
      protocol                   = string
      frontend_port              = number
      backend_port               = number
      enable_floating_ip         = bool
      frontend_ip_config_name    = string
    }))
  })
}
resource "azurerm_lb" "main" {
  name                = "myLoadBalancer"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  sku                 = "Standard"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "myFrontendIPConfig"
    public_ip_address_id = var.public_ip_id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "example" {
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.main.id
  name            = "myBackendPool"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "main" {
  name            = "myHealthProbe"
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.main.id
  protocol        = "Http"
  port            = 80
  request_path    = "/"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "main" {
  name                           = "myLoadBalancingRule"
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.main.id
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 80
  backend_port                   = 80
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "myFrontendIPConfig"
  //backend_address_pool_id        = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.main.id
  probe_id                       = azurerm_lb_probe.main.id
  enable_floating_ip             = false
}

# Assuming VM NICs should be associated with the backend pool
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address" "main" {
  for_each              = var.vm_nic_ids

  name                  = "BAPAddress-${each.key}"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.example.id
  ip_address            = each.value.ip_address
  virtual_network_id    = each.value.virtual_network_id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Vinay, Thank You for the detailed answer. But this is not I am looking for, I am using `azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association` resources to associate the VM NIC to backend pool. Also I don't want to attach all the VM NICs to backend pool. I have mapping requirement like `VM NIC 1` associate to `app-lb` ,  `DB Node 2 NIC 1` associate to `db-lb` and `DB Node 2 NIC 2` associate to `db-lb`

Comment: I have updated the working example without the module code for `azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association`.  The problem is when I transform the code into modules.